# C++ кавычки в строке

Tags: c++, powershell

Пытаюсь разработать программу на С++ по созданию древа каталогов и назначение разрешений к ним через PowerShell.

Как мне поставить в строку " или ' ?

Текущий код

```cpp
String gip = "start powershell.exe $acl = Get-ACL \\asiart-group.kz\Obmen\projects"+dirname+" \n $Rule=new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule (asiart-group\gip,Modify,ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit, None,Allow) \n $acl.AddAccessRule($Rule)";
```

Что мне примерно нужно получить

```cpp
String gip = "start powershell.exe $acl = Get-ACL \\asiart-group.kz\Obmen\projects"+dirname+" \n $Rule=new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ('asiart-group\gip','Modify','ContainerInherit','ObjectInherit','None','Allow') \n $acl.AddAccessRule($Rule)";
```

Comment: На **ru**.stackoverflow.com вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: попробуй оба варианта ,_,

Comment: Вам случайно не `\' \"` нужны?...

Answer (score 1):

Кавычки в строках языков C/C++ пишутся с помощью слэша, пример:

```
std::string str = "OOO \"My company\" and \`friends\`"
```

кавычки по краям будут восприниматься как границы строки, а внутренние кавычки, перед которыми стоит слэш (или бэкслэш, я не могу запомнить кто из них кто) воспринимаются как символы в строке.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно экранировать кавычки. 
Для этого используйте `\` перед символов.

```
String gip = "start powershell.exe $acl = Get-ACL \\asiart-group.kz\Obmen\projects"+dirname+" \n $Rule=new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule (asiart-group\gip,\'Modify\',\'ContainerInherit\',\'ObjectInherit\', \'None\',\'Allow\') \n $acl.AddAccessRule($Rule)";
```

Comment: `'` в строках работают и без экранирования. А вот `\\` экранировать нужно...